# I'm not able to log the checkbox value when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

Hey when checkbox is checked then my form gets submitted in "/delete" route. I'm able to submit my form but I'm not able to retrieve the checkbox value which I have assigned using ejs. I'm attaching the code snippets for the reference

Here's the ejs template html code:

```
<%- include('header'); -%>
    <div class="box">
        <h1 id="heading"><%= listTitle %></h1>
    </div>
    

    <div class="box">
        <% listItems.forEach(function(item){%>
        <form action="/delete" id = "listForm" method="POST"></form>
            <div class="item">
                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<%= item._id %>"
                onChange="this.form.submit()">
                <p><%=item.name%></p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <% }); %>

        <form action="/" method="POST" class="item">
            <input class="last-child" type="text" name="newItem" placeholder="New Item">
            <button type="submit" name="list" value=<%= listTitle %>>+</button>
        </form>

    </div>

    <script>
        document.querySelector("input[name='checkbox']").addEventListener("change",function(){
            if (this.checked){
                document.querySelector("form[id='listForm']").submit();
            }
        });
    </script>

<%- include('footer') -%>
```

Here's the Javascript code for POST method on "/delete" route:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){

    todo.find({}).then(function(todos){
        if(todos.length === 0){
            todo.insertMany(todoDefault).then(function(){
                console.log("Succesfully Inserted");
            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
    
            res.redirect("/");
        } else {
            res.render("list",{listTitle: "Today", listItems: todos});
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});

app.post("/delete",function(req,res){
   console.log(req.body.checkbox);
})
```

My get method for "/" route is working there is not issue in it.
Also I would like to know if there is any shortcut to submit the form when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        document.querySelector("input[name='checkbox']").addEventListener("change", function(e){
            if (e.target.checked){
                document.querySelector("form[id='listForm']").submit();
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer but when I made the changes to the code and logged the req.body in "/delete" route POST method. I'm getting "{}" as my log statement.